# java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid XXXXX lacks any of android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

Tags: android, android-securityexception

Note: This is not a duplicate, I tried a lot of solutions in similar StackOverflow questions and they didn't work in my case. Thank you for any help.

This crash appears to only happen on devices running an Android version older than 6.0. For example, it is crashing on an XT1032 running Android version 5.1. In that case, whenever I call this method, in my AppCompatActivity's onCreate method,

`AccountManager.get(this).addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(this, null, true);`

It crashes because it appears to not have the required permission (and I don't know why, because it is in the manifest). I believe it doesn't really enter the method, but crashes upon entering the method due to the @RequiresPermission line:

```
@RequiresPermission(GET_ACCOUNTS)
    public void addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(final OnAccountsUpdateListener listener,
            Handler handler, boolean updateImmediately) { ...
```

Here is the stack trace, plus some more logging code:

```
V/AccountManagerService: getAccounts: accountType null, caller's uid 10018, pid 23074
V/AccountManagerService:   caller uid 10018 has android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
V/AccountManagerService: getAccounts: accountType null, caller's uid 10018, pid 23074
V/AccountManagerService:   caller uid 10018 has android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
V/AccountManagerService:   caller uid 10009 has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
V/AccountManagerService: getAccounts: accountType com.google, caller's uid 10009, pid 1738
V/AccountManagerService:   caller uid 10009 has android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
V/AccountManagerService: getAccounts: accountType null, caller's uid 10018, pid 23074
V/AccountManagerService:   caller uid 10018 has android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
V/AccountManagerService: getAccounts: accountType null, caller's uid 10156, pid 13722
W/AccountManagerService:   caller uid 10156 lacks any of android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10156 lacks any of android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10156 lacks any of android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
                                                                                             at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.getAccounts(IAccountManager.java:728)
                                                                                             at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccounts(AccountManager.java:407)
                                                                                             at android.accounts.AccountManager.addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(AccountManager.java:2372)
```

What are the caller uids, and why is it using uid `10156` instead of `10018` or `10009` which have the permission?

I verified that my account type string in my AuthenticationService is the same as the authenticator.xml's accountType, and they both use hard-coded strings (not String resources).

```
public class AuthenticationService extends Service {

    public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.mywebsite";
    ...
    public static boolean createAccount(String username,...) {

        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(Application.getInstance());
        Account account = new Account(username, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```

And my authenticator:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:accountType="com.mywebsite"
                       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                       android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                       android:label="@string/app_name"
    />
```

I also have this:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` 
in the `<manifest>` tag, not the `<application>` tag.  Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mywebsite.android.department.departmentname” >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name”>
        <service android:name=".auth.AuthenticationService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This seems to be a clue in the Android documentation, but it doesn't seem to correlate with my error because I do have the permission in the manifest (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS):

> Note: Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), if an app shares the
>   signature of the authenticator that manages an account, it does not
>   need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about that account.
>   On Android 5.1 and lower, all apps need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to
>   read information about any account.

Comment: "What are the caller uids" -- they are the Linux user IDs (uids) of the apps calling some method that routes to `AccountManagerService`. "and why is it using uid 10156 instead of 10018 or 10009 which have the permission?" -- presumably, your app has uid 10156. Probably the other uids are for other apps on the device.

Comment: Ok I posted the whole manifest. Thank you @CommonsWare

Comment: Try This it will work API level 23
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that there was a conflict with a library I was using. Specifically, the library's support team told me:

> The layer SDK requests the GET_ACCOUNTS permission using a
>   maxSdkVersion of 18. It would appear that when the manifests get
>   merged this is overwriting the permission request in your manifest,
>   thus not requesting that permission for 19+.

The solution was to change my manifest from this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

to this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" tools:node="replace" />
```

Specifically, adding `tools:node="replace"`.

For more details, please see this answer to my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37013603/2423194